How to send an audio through API using Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter app that allows users to convert a video to audio and then send the audio for transcription to an API.
CONVERT VIDEO TO AUDIO
 Future<void> _convertVideoToAudio() async {
    if (_pickedVideo != null) {
      String videoPath = _pickedVideo!.path;
      _outputPath = await getOutputFilePath(); // Get platform-specific path
      print("_outputPath: $_outputPath");

      try {
        // await FFmpegKit.execute(
        //     "-i $videoPath -vn -acodec copy $_outputPath" // FFmpeg command
        //     );
        await FFmpegKit.execute(
            "-i $videoPath -vn -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 $_outputPath" // FFmpeg command
            );
        print("Video converted to audio successfully!");
        _showSuccessDialog(); // Display success dialog

        // await _audioPlayer.setFilePath(_outputPath);
        // await _audioPlayer.play();

        try {
          final String fileName = path
              .basename(_pickedVideo!.path)
              .replaceAll('.mp4', '.mp3'); // Replace extension
          // return '${downloadsDir!.path}/$fileName'; // Save in downloads folder
          final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final filePath = '${directory.path}/downloads/$fileName';
          final transcription =
              await _sendAudioForTranscription(filePath, fileName);

          if (transcription != null) {
            setState(() {
              _transcription = transcription;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _transcription = _outputPath;
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error in transcription request: $e');
          setState(() {
            _transcription = "Network request failed";
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error converting video: $e");
        _showErrorDialog(); // Display error dialog
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _pickedVideo = null; // Clear selected video
        });
      }
    } else {
      print("Please pick a video first.");
    }
  }

SEND THE AUDIO TO BE TRANSCRIBED
 Future<String?> _sendAudioForTranscription(
      String audioPath, String fileName) async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://mobix-api.vercel.app/api/transcribe'); // Your API route
      final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
      // final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      //   'file',
      //   audioPath,
      // );

      final fileBytes = File(audioPath);
      final bytes = await fileBytes.readAsBytes();

      final file =
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes, filename: fileName);

      request.files.add(file);

      final response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        final json = jsonDecode(responseBody);
        setState(() {
          _transcription = responseBody as String;
        });
        return json['transcription'] as String;
      } else {
        print('Error sending audio 0: ${response.statusCode}');
        setState(() {
          _transcription = 'Error sending audio 3: ${response.statusCode}';
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending audio 1: $e');
      setState(() {
        _transcription = 'Error sending audio 2: $e';
      });
    }
  }

However, I'm running into an issue where the audio file is not getting sent through the API. and it throws the following error.

Error sending audio 1: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.caption_app/app_flutter/downloads/1000002789.mp3' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

but I try to play the audio in the app itself after the extraction, and it works fine. What might be causing this issue, and how I can resolve it?
